# relation between access specifiers and using initializer lists for POD types in c++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, aggregate

take two following classes:

```
class Test1{
 public:
  Test1()=default;
  Test1(char in1,char in2):char1(in1),char2(in2){}
  char char1;
  char char2;
};
class Test2{
 public:
  Test2()=default;
  Test2(char in1,char in2):char1(in1),char2(in2){}
 private:
  char char1;
  char char2;
};
```

I know in c++0x both of these classes are considered as POD types and we can initialize objects of them using initializer lists as below:

```
Test1 obj1={'a','b'};//valid in c++0x
Test2 obj2={'a','b'};//valid in c++0x
```

But I wonder what the technical reason is that when we have different access specifiers in a class like below, it's not possible to use initializer list for initializing objects of that class and that class is not considered as a POD type ?

```
class Test{
 public:
  Test()=default;
  Test(char in1,char in2):char1(in1),char2(in2){}
  char char1;
 private:
  char char2;
};
Test obj={'a','b'};//invalid in c++0x
```

**In case you don't know definition of PODs in c++0x:**
A class/struct is considered a POD if it is trivial, standard-layout, and if all of its non-static members are PODs.

A trivial class or struct is defined as one that:

1. Has a trivial default constructor. This may use the default constructor syntax (SomeConstructor() = default;).
2. Has a trivial copy constructor, which may use the default syntax.
3. Has a trivial copy assignment operator, which may use the default syntax.
4. Has a trivial destructor, which must not be virtual.

A standard-layout class or struct is defined as one that:

1. Has only non-static data members that are of standard-layout type
2. Has the same access control (public, private, protected) for all non-static members
3. Has no virtual functions
4. Has no virtual base classes
5. Has only base classes that are of standard-layout type
6. Has no base classes of the same type as the first defined non-static member
7. Either has no base classes with non-static members, or has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static members. In essence, there may be only one class in this class's hierarchy that has non-static members.

**In case you don't know what a trivial constructor or operator is:**
Compiler generates a trivial one of each of following items for a class, in case it isn't user-declared:
Copy constructor, destructor and copy assignment operator.
And also if there's no user-declared constructor for a class, a trivial default constructor is generated for that class, in case there are any user-declared constructors you can use the syntax(SomeConstructor() = default;) to make your own trivial default constructor.

Comment: None of the classes in the question are POD, even by the C++0x definition of POD. In C++0x, a POD class type must be trivial, meaning it has a trivial default constructor. Your classes have no default constructor.  The first two classes are _standard-layout classes_, though.

Comment: the first two classes are PODs, read additional info I added.

Comment: @Pooria:  All three of your classes have a user-declared constructor, therefore there is no implicitly declared default constructor.

Comment: you just don't get the point, all three classes have implicitly declared default constructors because I didn't declare a default constructor !!!

Comment: @Pooria:  Wrong.  If there is _any_ user-declared constructor, then no default constructor is implicitly declared.  Your classes all have a user declared constructor.  Ergo, none of your classes have an implicitly declared default constructor.

Comment: No that rule has changed in c++0x, go take a look at the following link:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t703250-c-0x-pods-and-constructors.html
You might also want to take a look at N2960 and N3000 papers(Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++).

Comment: @Pooria:  N3092 §12.1.5:  "If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted."  You can declare the trivial default constructor using the ` = default;` syntax, but you have not done that for any of these classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test{
 public:
  Test()=default;
  Test(char in1,char in2):char1(in1),char2(in2){}
  char char1;
 private:
  char char2;
};
```

considering above class following syntax is valid in c++0x:

```
Test obj={'a','b'};//valid in c++0x
```

The final proposal is [**here**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The "technical" reason is due to the following:

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspeciﬁed (C++0x §9.2/12).

So long as all the nonstatic data members have the same access control, their order is well-specified; otherwise their order is unspecified.

Comment: so why doesn't compiler put initializer values in correct order since it probably knows the correct order itself ?

Comment: @Pooria: the compiler does put initializers in the correct order.  GCC warns you when it reorganizes initialization to be different than what was declared in the constructor.

Comment: @Caspin: I was talking about when there are different access specifiers and in that case, using initializer list as I mentioned, is illegal.

Comment: @Pooria:  The text I quoted is why the data members of a standard layout class must all have the same access control.  Initializer lists are effectively an extension of the current aggregate initialization.  I admit, though, that I haven't done much research into initializer lists; I haven't read any of the papers on them and my primary compiler (VC10) doesn't support them.